# add fields to table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#selectDay').bind('change', function () {
    $('.hours').show();
});

function fncCreateElement() {
    var mySpan = document.getElementById('mySpan');
    var myElement1 = document.createElement('select');
    myElement1.setAttribute('type', "text");
    myElement1.setAttribute('name', "fromTime");
    mySpan.appendChild(myElement1);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uahbF/)

After choosing day I can select from and until time, this works.
What I need is when I click `add date` a new row will appear where can I chose new day (Sunday - Saturday ) and then `FROM` and `UNTIL` time like first one that already works.

The table look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>day</td>
        <td>From Hour</td>
        <td>Until Hour</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="selectDay">
                <option value=''>Choose Time</option>
                <option value='1'>Sunday</option>
                <option value='2'>Monday</option>
                <option value='3'>Tuesday</option>
                <option value='4'>Wednesday</option>
                <option value='5'>Thursday</option>
                <option value='6'>Friday</option>
                <option value='7'>Saturday</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="hours" style='display: none'>
                <select name="fromTime" class="mediumField">
                    <option value='6'>6</option>
                    <option value='7'>7</option>
                    <option value='8'>8</option>
                    <option value='9'>9</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='11'>11</option>
                    <option value='12'>12</option>
                    <option value='13'>13</option>
                    <option value='14'>14</option>
                    <option value='15'>15</option>
                    <option value='16'>16</option>
                    <option value='17'>17</option>
                    <option value='18'>18</option>
                    <option value='19'>19</option>
                    <option value='20'>20</option>
                    <option value='21'>21</option>
                    <option value='22'>22</option>
                    <option value='23'>23</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="hours" style='display: none'>
                <select name="untilTime" class="mediumField">
                    <option value='6'>6</option>
                    <option value='7'>7</option>
                    <option value='8'>8</option>
                    <option value='9'>9</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='11'>11</option>
                    <option value='12'>12</option>
                    <option value='13'>13</option>
                    <option value='14'>14</option>
                    <option value='15'>15</option>
                    <option value='16'>16</option>
                    <option value='17'>17</option>
                    <option value='18'>18</option>
                    <option value='19'>19</option>
                    <option value='20'>20</option>
                    <option value='21'>21</option>
                    <option value='22'>22</option>
                    <option value='23'>23</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should post rendered html not php... is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/NZRhh/

Comment: Hi @Sergio - not exactly. clicking on "add date" should add row with 3 selectboxs. the first one is the DAY selectbox, and when I chose him div with 2 more select box appear (same as in my link above)

Comment: Then post rendered html so we can see your code properly

Comment: I edit my first post @Sergio

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uahbF/

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change','.selectDay', function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('.hours').show();
    });
});
function fncCreateElement() {
    var new_table = $('table').eq(0).clone();
    $('table').last().after(new_table);
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EyruX/)